# How to include git branch in installing from requirements in Python?

Tags: python, git, pip, requirements.txt, python-install

Hi I need to install from a branch of a git repo. I want to include it on the requirements.txt so that it would install using the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`

What I know is how to install from master branch (See git ssh entry below):

This is my `requirements.txt`

```
networkx==2.4
numpy==1.18.1
opencv-python==4.2.0.32
scipy==1.4.1
git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/project/project-utils.git
```

What if I want to install from a specific branch namely `1-fix-test` on `ssh://git@gitlab.com/project/project-utils.git`.

How do I include the branch name with the ssh address?

Comment: No. The chosen answer does.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bpip%5D+branch

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [document](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/#git), you can add branch name or commit hash after `@`:

```
git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/project/project-utils.git@1-fix-test
```

Comment: @scrowler I’ve just updated the link, please check now.